# How to make a loop in scrapy response.follow?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping Dmoz website. And I am scraping each page but I don't want to write `response.follow()` each time. Instead I want to make a loop. How to make it so that I just write `page_name` and `function_name` instead of writing the whole line of code again and again.

```
    yield response.follow(self.about_page, self.parse_about, meta={'items': items})
    yield response.follow(self.editor, self.parse_editor, meta={'items': items})
    yield response.follow(self.suggestion, self.suggest_site, meta={'items':items})
    yield response.follow(self.help_page, self.parse_help, meta={'items':items})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean formatting your code? Try:

```
dct = [
    (self.about_page, self.parse_about),
    (self.editor, self.parse_editor),
    (self.suggestion, self.suggest_site),
    (self.help_page, self.parse_help),
]
for page, callback in dct:
    yield response.follow(page, callback, meta={'items': items})
```

Comment: Thank you. I have another problem if you could solve.

Comment: Sorry I was not aware of. Now I have done. But I have question regarding another problem